# Phoenix JerseyServletContainer Exception in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, hadoop, hbase, cloudera-cdh, apache-phoenix

I have a maven generated war file which consists of phoenix-client-1.2.0.jar.

The cloudera version i am using is 5.5.4.

This phoenix client jar consists of a class called JerseyServletContainerInitializer.

This same class is also present in one of the jersey-server jars of tomcat 7.

While server start up, The tomcat refers to the JerseyServletContainerInitializer jar from the phoenix-client.jar. hence throwing the below exception

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1661)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1569)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1277)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           ... 10 more

I cannot exclude either of the jars. What is the work around this?